# I need to convert NSDate objects to UDate objects (ICU)

Tags: nsdate, icu

I need to convert NSDate objects to (ICU) UDate objects.  I have read that they are similar, but I was hoping that someone might have already investigated doing this and can help me shortcut the process.  So has anyone got some sample code where they have done this, or can point me in the direction of where I can determine how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but probably `(UDate)([someNsDate timeIntervalSince1970]/1000.0)`

UDate = milliseconds since 1970 (double)

timeIntervalSince1970 = seconds since 1970 (double)

Comment: Probably (UDate)([someNsDate timeIntervalSince1970]*1000.0)